# Cloud function is not triggered by pub/sub topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have several cloud functions running in my GCP project which are connected to a pub/sub topic. They all subscribe to a different topic.

When starting the function, I can see a subscription is created on the topic and when sending messages the pub/sub topic is receiving them. However, the corresponding cloud functions are not triggered and are not processing the messages. I can see the unacked message count on the subscription increasing so until the subscription everything seems to be working fine.

I am talking here about my production environment. I have this exact same setup in my development project, where it's working seamlessly. The only difference is that I am assigning a specific service account to the functions in the production environment. But I believe that if the service account was the issue, there would already be an error when deploying the function.

Does anyone have advice on how to debug and solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you see any errors in the logs? Especially 403 or 401 on your Cloud Functions logs?

Comment: Ah yes, there are quite some 403 warning logs saying "The request was not authenticated. Either allow unauthenticated invocations or set the proper Authorization header. Read more at https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/authenticating Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#unauthorized-client" Does this mean that I have to allow pub/sub to call the function?

Comment: How did you deploy/link your PubSub with your Cloud Functions?

Comment: I deployed using the gcloud command and gave the --trigger-topic as a parameter. Which works fine on my development project

Comment: Yes, it should work automatically. Are the topics in the same projects as your Cloud Functions? Do you use the same Cloud Functions generation in dev and in production?

Comment: Yes they are in the same project and yes I execute the exact same gcloud commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve this, using this link: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Serverless/Cloud-Function-2nd-gen-cant-hit-cloud-run-deployed-by-them/m-p/625594

I had to add the Cloud Run Invoker role to my service account that was attached to the Cloud Function.